# How to validate uniqueness with scope?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I've got:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :year, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.year
  field :month, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.month
  field :day, :type => Integer, :default => Time.now.utc.day

  validates :day, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:month,:year] }
end
```

I do the following twice:

```
Foo.create(:day => 24, :year => 2013, :month => 5)
```

I get no validation error. Instead, I have two of the same records. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: How quickly are the two creates executed, if they are fired immediately there is an inherit race condition here. Perhaps the initial write is cached before the second create validates. My suggestion would be to set a multi key unique constraint in mongodb directly. `db.foos.ensureIndex( { "day": 1, "year": 1, "month": 1 }, { unique: true } )`

Comment: Not immediately. I can wait 30 seconds or even a few minutes and I would still get duplicate records. No race condition anywhere. I can consider the unique constraint directly in Mongodb, as a last resort. However, I am hoping for a way to do this via Mongoid (app layer).

Comment: In production you should do both, if getting hit with multiple concurrent inserts it is possible to run into the above race condition. As for the problem at hand, I do not see anything wrong syntactically or logically. Possible problem: `Mongoid behaves slightly different to Active Record when using #valid? on already persisted data. Active Record's #valid? will run all validations whereas Mongoid's #valid? will only run validations on documents that are in memory as an optimization.` http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html

Comment: For this instance, the inserts run on a single thread (via a worker/cron job). Not concurrently. Doubt a race condition will happen here

Comment: From http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html, for validates_uniqueness_of :name ... validates :name, uniqueness: true ... Validate that an attribute is unique. Note that for embedded documents, this will only check that the field is unique within the context of the parent document, not the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
validates_uniqueness_of :day, scope: [:month,:year]
```